# Match rows that include one of each at least once in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a users table:

```
ID  Name  OID   TypeID
1    a     1      1
2    b     1      2 
3    c     1      3
4    d     2      1
5    e     2      1
6    f     2      2
7    g     3      2
8    h     3      2
9    i     3      2
```

for this table, I want to filter by OID and TypeID so that I get the rows that it is filtered by OID and that includes all 1, 2, and 3 in TypeID.

For example, where OID=1, we have 1, 2, and 3 in TypeID but I shouldn't get the rows with IDs 4-6 because for IDs 4-6, OIDs are the same but TypeID does not include all of each(1, 2, and 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
select oid
from table t
where typeid in (1,2,3)
group by oid
having count(*) = 3;
```

If, `oid` contain duplicate `typeid` then you can use `count(distinct typeid)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you could use exists

```
select oid from table t1
where exists ( select 1 from table t1 where t1.oid=t2.oid
                          group by t2.oid
                          having (distinct TypeID)=3
             )
```

Asume  TypeID 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql-server, you can try this.

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE(ID INT,  Name VARCHAR(5),   OID INT,   TypeID INT)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES
(1 , 'a', 1, 1),
(2 , 'b', 1, 2), 
(3 , 'c', 1, 3),
(4 , 'd', 2, 1),
(5 , 'e', 2, 1),
(6 , 'f', 2, 2),
(7 , 'g', 3, 2),
(8 , 'h', 3, 2),
(9 , 'i', 3, 2)


SELECT * FROM @SampleData D
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM @SampleData D1
            RIGHT JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) T(TypeID) ON D1.TypeID = T.TypeID 
                AND D.OID = D1.OID
        WHERE D1.TypeID IS NULL
    )
```

Result:

```
ID          Name  OID         TypeID
----------- ----- ----------- -----------
1           a     1           1
2           b     1           2
3           c     1           3
```